# How to connect Jitsi Client to ejabberd Server?

Tags: ejabberd, pidgin, jitsi

I'm trying to connect Jitsi with ejabberd but getting error "Not connected to server" while server is running and connected to Pidgin client successfully. Can anyone help?

Comment: You need to provide more info if you would like meaningful reply (logs, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try editing your connection setup in your account profile:

- Connect service: *your host*
- port           : 5222

See if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Just check proper server configuration for port and server ip once

And have you checked "Allow Non-Secure Connection" checkbox in Jitsi ? If not than check that box and try again